# Cancellation law for direct sums

Tags: linear-algebra, direct-sum

Let $V$ be a vector space and $U,W$ and $Z$ subspaces of $V$.

Does $V = W \oplus Z$ and $V = U \oplus Z$
necessarily means that $W = U$?

Thanks!

Comment: Why would you call such a property transitivity? It would be called something like a 'cancellation law for direct sums'. But as the answer points out, it is false anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, for example $\mathbb{R}^2 = \operatorname{span}((1,0)) \oplus \operatorname{span}((0,1))$ and $\mathbb{R}^2 = \operatorname{span}((1,0))\oplus \operatorname{span}((1,1))$.