# Prove that two subspaces are not equal under a given condition

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Prove or give a counterexample:
>
> If $U_1, U_2, W$ are subspaces of $V$ such that $U_1 \bigoplus W = U_2 \bigoplus W$, then $U_1 = U_2$.

**Proof**

Let $u_1+w \in U_1 \bigoplus$ W. Since $U_1\bigoplus W= U_2\bigoplus W, u_1+w \in U_2\bigoplus W$. Since $w \in U_2 \bigoplus W, -w \in U_2 \bigoplus W$. Therefore $ u_1 \in U_2 \bigoplus W $.Since $U_1$ and $W$ have no elements in common,$u_1 \not\in W$ . Therefore $u_1 \in U_2$. Therefore$ U_1 \subseteq U_2.$ Similarly other side inclusion works. Therefore $U_1=U_2$.

What is wrong with this proof?

Comment: There are lots of elements in $U_2\oplus W$ that are in neither $U_2$ nor $W$. Specifically, if $u\in U_2$ is nonzero, and $w\in W$ is nonzero, then $u+w$ is in neither $U_2$ nor in $W$ (check that). So your claim that “Therefore $u_1\in U_2$”  does not follow.

Comment: By the way, you show use the simple $+$ if you're referring to Minkowski sum, ie., $A+B=\{a+b\mid a\in A~,~b\in B\}$ (the $\bigoplus$ is generally used for direct sum which doesn't seem to be the case here)

Comment: @learner: Have you heard of internal direct sums?

Comment: @Arturo Magidin  Thanks. I can see my mistake now.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin: I had, but I wasn't under the impression that it would be isomorphic to the (external) direct sum in this case. I stand corrected.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cancellation law for direct sums](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2178841/cancellation-law-for-direct-sums)

Comment: @learner i have seen that question, but i think my question is related to this particular erroneous proof of mine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not true. The error is in this line:

> Since $U_1$ and $W$ have no elements in common, $u_1 \not\in W$. Therefore $u_1 \in U_2$.

It is not true in general that if $x \in A \oplus B$ then $x \in A$ or $x \in B$. (Perhaps you are confusing the properties of the direct sum $U_2 \oplus W$, with the properties of the union $U_2 \cup W$, which in general is not a subspace.) An instructive example is taking $A$ to be the $x$-axis in $\Bbb R^2$ and $B$ the $y$-axis. Then, $\Bbb R = A \oplus B$ but, e.g., $(1, 1)$ is in neither $A$ nor $B$.

Comment: What do you mean “the direct sum, which in general is not a subspace”? Was that clause meant to apply to the union?

Comment: Yes, of course---I originally had the two concepts in the other order. I'm grateful for the catch, and I've fixed the error.